# How to print one element before matching item in list

Tags: python

I want to print out the matching item in list and the item before the matched one.

mylist=['apple:','orange:','pink','kiwi:']

i am expecting to get this kind of output:

```
orange:
pink
```

my code:

```
for y in mylist:
    if ":" not in y:
        print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing (I think) is to use `enumerate` so that when you find a match you can easily access the previous item by its index:

```
for i, word in enumerate(mylist):
    if ":" not in word:
        print(mylist[i-1])
        print(word)
```